# Best way to apply cameraViewTransform to UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage? iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, zooming, uiimagepickercontroller, background-process

I'm trying to apply the `cameraViewTransform` from my `UIImagePickerController` to the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` (the out coming `UIImage` from the camera). The only way I managed to do this is by printing the `UIImage` on an `UIImageView` and then using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext();` to take a screenshot of the `UIImageView` I have.

The thing is, printing the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` to an `UIImageView`, and then zooming and taking a screenshot takes a long time to process and also freezes the iPhone. (That's because that `UIImage` is in full resolution, and I also want it to stay in full resolution.)

My Question is... is there a better way to apply the `cameraViewTransform` to the `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` image? Or is there a faster way to print my image on the image view?

Thank you so much guys for your time, I really appreciate it!!! :)